# Convert python list into datetime format to extract months from it

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format

I have a date in the form of a list in python, which I need to convert to datetime format so that I can get month from it. But I am getting the error:
ValueError: time data "['2019-06-27']" does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

```
for i, e in reversed(list(enumerate(dates_list))):
        if dates_list[i][0] == 'Monday':
            print(dates_list[i][1])
            weekstart.append(dates_list[i][1])

    format_str = '%Y-%m-%d'
    datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(weekstart), format_str)
    m = datetime_obj.strftime("%m")
```

dates_list:
[('Monday', '2019-06-24'), ('Tuesday', '2019-06-25'), ('Wednesday', '2019-06-26'), ('Thursday', '2019-06-27'), ('Friday', '2019-06-28'), ('Saturday', '2019-06-29'), ('Sunday', '2019-06-30')]

weekstart: 2019-06-24

Can someone help me to get a month out of weekstart?

Comment: Can you fix your indentation

Comment: This worked:

weekstart = None
    for i, e in reversed(list(enumerate(dates_list))):
        if dates_list[i][0] == 'Monday':
            print(dates_list[i][1])
            weekstart = dates_list[i][1]

    if weekstart:
        format_str = '%Y-%m-%d'
        datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(weekstart, format_str)
    m = datetime_obj.strftime("%m")

Comment: Add this to the question instead @RahulAnand

Comment: okay @DeveshKumarSingh

Answer (score 0):

```
weekstart = None
    for i, e in reversed(list(enumerate(dates_list))):
        if dates_list[i][0] == 'Monday':
            print(dates_list[i][1])
            weekstart = dates_list[i][1]

    if weekstart:
        format_str = '%Y-%m-%d'
        datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(weekstart, format_str)
    m = datetime_obj.strftime("%m")
```

Comment: in the question, not as an answer, also point out which line causes the error for you, and what is the expected output